# Get the username with GitLab / markdown

Tags: html, markdown, gitlab

I'm a newbie, and maybe I don't have the good keywords for my search.
Here's my question.

I'm trying to generate a md (markdown) file and I want to know if it is possible to get the current username, as i'm inside a gitlab project.

To get an output like

```
I'm "username"
```

when reading the markdown file.

Thanks for your explanation !

Comment: how are you generating the Markdown file?  If you're using bash, it's simply: `echo "I'm \"$(whoami)\"" > something.md`

Comment: I'm inside firefox, accessing gitlab, so I unfortunately can't do it !

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32254521/866026

Comment: Perhaps this is not what you want, but a shortcut for GitLab namespaces is using `@mentions`. So, your username is `@username`. But, as I said, I'm not sure this is good enough for your needs...

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you are just talking about a markdown file in a GitLab repository. In that case, it's not possible since it's only a [static file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_web_page) and the GitLab server doesn't do any processing on it. So there's no way to have it display differently for each user.