# Global variables in MkDocs

Tags: html, markdown, mkdocs

I have a documentation project made with [MkDocs](http://www.mkdocs.org/). I would like to define global variables in the configuration file (`mkdocs.yml`) to be used in the markdown pages (`*.md`).

Reading this [issue](https://github.com/mkdocs/mkdocs/issues/144), it seems it can be done by including an `extra` configuration in the `mkdocs.yml` file, for example:

```
extra:
    version: 1.0
```

... and then, use that variable in page for example as follows:

```
---> My version: {{ config.extra.version }}
```

I tried that, but unfortunately it is not working in my example (no variable substution):

[image]

- Am I doing something wrong?
- Is is possible to make this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is not possible at this time.

You say that you "use that variable in page". I'm assuming you mean a "Markdown" page. At this time template variables are not available in the Markdown pages. The template engine is not even run against the Markdown. The output of the Markdown parser is one of the variables passed to the template. For a more detailed explanation of how that works, see my answer to [How do you include flask/jinja2 code inside a markdown file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32254521/866026).

Specific to MkDocs, there is an open issue ([#304](https://github.com/mkdocs/mkdocs/issues/304)) discussing adding a feature to support some limited templating within the Markdown pages, but it is scheduled for post-1.0, so its not a top priority at this time.

Comment: It seems both these plugins mentioned in most recent answer above are not updated/maintained. The last releases were more than 1 or 2 years ago. What is the current alternative? Is this now natively supported by mkdocs?

Answer (score 8):

The given answer is out of date as this can be done with plugins like [macros](https://mkdocs-macros-plugin.readthedocs.io/) or [markdownextradata](https://github.com/rosscdh/mkdocs-markdownextradata-plugin) as mentioned above except you would just reference `{{ version }}`.

Answer (score 3):

As an update, it is possible to insert the variables from the `extra` slot in `mkocs.yml`, exactly as you describe.

To make this work, you need to install the [markdownextradata](https://github.com/rosscdh/mkdocs-markdownextradata-plugin) plugin.